# Save a ImageView state after exit App (onSaveInstanceState)

Tags: android, image, imageview

I have a app where i allow the user to pick a picture from galery and it use as PROFILE PICTURE, pick a picture and set in a "ImageView" in my app.

The problem is that when the app is closed, ou the activity is changed the picture desapear, or back de default picture again, i want save this picture state for when back to activity or when close and re-open the app the picture continue there and dont need set all over again. 
I am new in developing, please if you can help me looking my code below and give make the needed changes and give me the ready code i will be really deeply thankful cause i spent several days for do it and still i cant. I need a ready code cause i am new in developing and if you try explain something i will not understand.

Here is my code where i pick the picture:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
String imgDecodableString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the onSaveInstanceState Activity lifecycle methods. Here's a blog post regarding its best practices. 
http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en